# Spectrum of the GraphData

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm new in using Mathematica.

I need to generate graph spectrums for line graphs of all graphs with vertices number smaller than 5.

I used this command to generate all LineGraps:

```
GraphData[#, "LineGraph"] & /@ GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]
```

It generates "plots" of all line graphs.

If i try to do this:

```
GraphData[#, "Spectrum"] & /@ GraphData[#, "LineGraph", ] & /@ 
 GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]
```

it still generates only the "plots", not spectrum.

Can somebody help me how to generate spectrum of each of these line graphs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a hanging comma in `GraphData[#, "LineGraph", ] & `. And you probably want to us `GraphData[#, "Spectrum"] & /@  GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately i removed coma and still it doesn't work and shows plots. I didn;t want GraphData[#, "Spectrum"] & /@ GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5] because it shows spectrums of all graphs between 2 and 5 vertices and i want their LineGraph's spectrums (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph)

Comment: Perhaps it's good to point out that the `GraphData` function merely queries a database. It does not compute anything. You need to pass *the name of a graph* to it, not the graph itself.  Given a graph, you can compute it's `LineGraph` directly, or its spectrum using `Eigenvalues@AdjacencyMatrix[graph]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `"LineGraph"` is not necessarily stored in `GraphData` and that `GraphData[#,`"LineGraph"`]&` returns a `Graph` object and not a name of the graph. But one can easily compute the spectrum of any `Graph` as the eigenvalues if its adjacency matrix:

```
Eigenvalues[AdjacencyMatrix[GraphData[#, "LineGraph"]]] & /@ 
 GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]
```

Comment: Thank You very much :) I started with Eigenvalues, but later i saw Property "Spectrum" so I tried to use it. Now it works!

Comment: You're welcome. And enjoy Mathematica!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use the `"LineGraph"` in the middle, just pass the first `GraphData` elements to the `"Spectrum"` one.

You can try

```
Table[GraphData[g, "Spectrum"], {g, GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]}]
```

---

*Explanation:*

`GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]` returns a table of elements. You can use the elements from this table to put yet in another GraphData.

---

*Edit:*

I just saw your comment about wanting `LineGraph` spectra, not the `Graph` spectra. However, when you pass a `LineGraph` to `GraphData[#, "Spectrum"]`, it doesn't work.

The output looks like this:
[image]

---

Are you sure that you don't want this? Because, the way I see it, `2;;5` range has a collection of graphs. For each of these graphs there is a *name* (1st column), a *line graph plot* (2nd column) and a *spectrum* (3rd column):

[image]

P.s.:
This is the code for the output above:

```
Table[{
   g,
   GraphData[g, "LineGraph"],
   GraphData[g, "Spectrum"]
   },
  {g, GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]}] // TraditionalForm
```

Answer (score 4):

You had two problems.

1. You were missing the "Name" subproperty
2. You need to use parentheses so that the input is parsed the way you want (`&` has very low precedence):

So, you could get your code working as follows:

```
GraphData[#, "Spectrum"] & /@ (GraphData[#, "LineGraph", "Name"] &) /@ GraphData["Connected", 2 ;; 5]
```

> GraphData::notdef: GraphData has no value associated with the specified argument(s).
>
> GraphData::notdef: GraphData has no value associated with the specified argument(s).
>
> GraphData::notdef: GraphData has no value associated with the specified argument(s).
>
> General::stop: Further output of GraphData::notdef will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> {{-2, -2, Root[4 - 4 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 0, 
>     Root[4 - 4 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 1, 
>     Root[4 - 4 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {-2, 
>     Root[2 - 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 0, Root[2 - 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2],
>      Root[2 - 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 
>     Root[-2 - 5 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], Root[-2 - 5 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>     1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), Root[-2 - 5 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {-2, -1, -1, 
>     1/2 (3 - Sqrt[17]), 1, 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[17])}, {-1, -1, 2}, {-2, -2, 0, 0, 1, 
>     3}, {-2, -2, 1/2 (3 - Sqrt[33]), 0, 0, 1, 
>     1/2 (3 + Sqrt[33])}, {Root[2 - 5 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], -1, -1, 
>     Root[2 - 5 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>     Root[2 - 5 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 
>     1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 2}, {-2, 
>     Root[4 - 4 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], -1, 0, 
>     Root[4 - 4 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>     Root[4 - 4 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {-2, 1 - Sqrt[5], 0, 0, 
>     1 + Sqrt[5]}, {Root[1 - 3 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], -1, 
>     Root[1 - 3 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
>     Root[1 - 3 #1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {-2, -2, -1, 
>     Root[2 - #1 - 4 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], Root[2 - #1 - 4 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 1, 
>     Root[2 - #1 - 4 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, {-2, 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 
>     Root[2 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 
>     Root[2 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], Root[2 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}, 
>    GraphData[Missing["NotAvailable"], "Spectrum"], 
>    GraphData[Missing["NotAvailable"], "Spectrum"], {-2, 
>     Root[4 + 2 #1 - 6 #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1], 
>     Root[4 + 2 #1 - 6 #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 2], 0, 
>     Root[4 + 2 #1 - 6 #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 3], 
>     Root[4 + 2 #1 - 6 #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 4]}, {-2, -2, 1/2 (3 - Sqrt[33]), 
>     0, 0, 1, 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[33])}, {0}, {-1, 1}, {-Sqrt[2], 0, Sqrt[
>     2]}, {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 
>     1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}, {1/2 (1 - Sqrt[17]), -1, 0, 
>     1/2 (1 + Sqrt[17])}, {-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6}, {-2, 0, 0, 
>     2}, {-1, -1, -1, 3}, {Root[2 + #1 - 5 #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1], -1, 
>     Root[2 + #1 - 5 #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 &, 2], 
>     Root[2 + #1 - 5 #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 &, 3], 
>     Root[2 + #1 - 5 #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 &, 4]}, {-2, -2, 0, 0, 0, 4}, {-1, -1, 
>     2}, GraphData[Missing["NotAvailable"], "Spectrum"]}

Messages are generated because [`GraphData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData) does not include all of the line graphs in its database.

Comment: A good question would be: given a `Graph`, how to find it in `GraphData`. One can query all graphs with the same number of vertices, compute the `CanonicalGraph` of each, then search based on that. It's ugly though. I wonder if there's something more direct. It could be sped up by pre-filtering by basic properties, such as the edge count.

Comment: ToEntity: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToEntity.html